# What is the range of values that can be expected in the result of Principal Component Analysis (PCA)?

Tags: pca, normalization, svd

I want to normalize all of my preprocessing techniques between 0 and 1 so I want to know what the PCA range of values is so that I can apply a proper normalization to it. I applied PCA by using the result of SVD.

For example, I saw that the SVD range of values was limited to positive values, so I feature scaled to normalize the values between 0 and 1. Is there any such range for PCA?

Answer (score 0):

The output of PCA is a set of eigenvectors each associated with an eigenvalue. The eigenvalues are non-negative real values. The egenvectors are all unity vectors (i.e. with Euclidean norm 1.0);  their components can be positive or negative real values. If you have calculated PCA with SVD, the eigenvalues of PCA are just the squared value of the singular values of SVD.